# Maven cannot identify JAVA_HOME on macOS 11.6.7

Tags: maven

I am on macOS 11.6.7. My JAVA_HOME variable is set to `~/.zshenv` as:

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

My terminal output for both `echo $JAVA_HOME` and `mvn --version` are as follows:

```
<redacted> ~ % echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-18.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
<redacted>~ % mvn --version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.
```

I have attempted to `source ~/.zshenv` as well as restarting shell. The `JAVA_HOME` variable is read correctly even still. What am I missing? Are there other configuration files I have to check/set for Maven specifically?

Comment: Does `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` give the expected result?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes, when I run that exact line I see the desired Java version printed

Comment: How did you install Maven?

Comment: Installed it with homebrew. `brew install maven`

Comment: Try with the official zip distribution.